# How "Lock to focal plane" function works?

Tags: grease-pencil

Grease Pencil Blur Effect: how "Lock to focal plane" function works?

[image]

As I understand from description, it blurs GP-objects in proportion of distance between object and focal plane. But when i tried this option can't see any significant difference between "in focus" and "out of focus" objects.

In my example top monkeys has this setup:

[image]

bottom:

[image]

As you see dof effect enabled, and works on meshes, but not on monkeys. Am I doing something wrong, or it just a bug, and am I need to report it?

[image]